# How can I tell GCC not to align main's stack to 16-byte boundary?

Tags: gcc, stack, alignment, program-entry-point

GCC is doing some voodoo where it is aligning my `main`'s stack, saving the location of the arguments into `ecx`

```
0x08049060      8d4c2404       lea ecx, [arg_4h]                       ; 4 ; [13] -r-x section size 465 named .text
0x08049064      83e4f0         and esp, 0xfffffff0
0x08049067      ff71fc         push dword [ecx - 4]
0x0804906a      55             push ebp
0x0804906b      89e5           mov ebp, esp
0x0804906d      51             push ecx
```

And, then later,

```
0x080490a4      8b4dfc         mov ecx, dword [local_4h]
0x080490a7      83c410         add esp, 0x10
0x080490aa      c9             leave
0x080490ab      8d61fc         lea esp, [ecx - 4]
0x080490ae      c3             ret
```

I believe I understand *why* GCC is doing what it's doing ([you can read about it here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/18969/22669)), but the binary that I'm trying to rebuild from source lacks these instructions in the tutorial, and I want to generate assembly as close to the tutorial as possible.

Both of these are return from `file`,

> stack0: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18,

---

I've tried `__attribute__ ((packed))` on main, and `#pragma pack` neither of which worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the stack alignment, by telling GCC to align to `2` bytes, rather than `16`

```
-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2
```

There will likely be some performance implications.

---

Caveat from [Peter Cordes,](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes)

> This will violate the ABI for the whole rest of the program, not maintaining the 16-byte alignment that the Linux version of the i386 SysV ABI guarantees on program entry and before calls to other functions. So compiler-generated code using SSE instructions may segfault. It may be possible with a function attribute on main to tell it that the incoming stack alignment is correct. This might not be a problem for your use-case, but it's an important caveat. Also it can break _Atomic uint64_t local vars that other threads get references to.

Comment: Note that the value 2 means align to 2 to the power 2 = 4 bytes

Comment: This will violate the ABI for the whole rest of the program, not maintaining the 16-byte alignment that the Linux version of the i386 SysV ABI guarantees on program entry and before calls to other functions.  So compiler-generated code using SSE instructions may segfault. It may be possible with a function attribute on main to tell it that the incoming stack alignment is correct.  This might not be a problem for your use-case, but it's an important caveat.  Also it can break `_Atomic uint64_t` local vars that other threads get references to.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm going to just copy and paste that into the answer too.